# Git stash apply has erased all unstaged files

Tags: git

I have `git stash`-ed my local files using simply using git stash. I had some staged (and locally commited) files, and some unstaged changes (within the same files, I had staged by chunks).

Then, I did a `git pull --rebase` (since some changes were done in remote), and then `git stash apply` (Probably here I should have done `git stash --index` ?).

Unfortunately, I have lost all the unstaged changes after doing the `git stash apply`, and I don't know how to retrieve them. How can I solve this?

Edit: I have not lost these changes as mentioned in the answer by @LeGec,  so I am able to retrieve them, after (long story short) I pull and commit what I need.
The real issue is that I had commited some changes, which I should not have commited, so I tried resetting the commit, in order to commit again with only what is needed. While doing all of this, I lost the unstanged changes.
Just doing everything in the right order have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

first and foremost: your stash *still* contains the unstaged files, you can run `git stash show` or `git log --oneline --name-status stash` to see that.

---

If `git stash apply` met conflicts, git will leave the changes in the index (the staging area) and ask you to handle the conflicts. This may be a reason why you see all changes staged, and none listed as unstaged.

Check your `git status`.